# Importing large data from blogger to WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, blogs, blogger

I want to migrate Google blog to WordPress. And backup data from blogger is around 200MB. I tried importing using the Wordpress Import Blogger plugin. Because the data is too large, So I did changes in php.ini file to increase the value of these variables: post_max_size=200M, upload_max_file_size=200M and memory_limit=1280M

But I am not able to import the data to wordpress. It shows the blank screen. And there is no error in the console log as well.

Please help me to resolve the problem. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Look in the php error log and tell us what the error is

Comment: There is no error log.

Comment: Where have you looked

Comment: on root directory where normally error log create.

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: I am using Windows 10

Comment: Did you install yuor AMP stack yourself or did you use WAMPServer/XAMPP or something similiar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174649/discussion-between-yogesh-shakya-and-riggsfolly).

Comment: @YogeshShakya when you start the migration process, can you also check your CPU/RAM usage. Does it peak out or nothing happens? The default Blogger Importer provided by WordPress isn't able to handle very large import sizes.  Either you will have to write a custom script to parse the XML file or use a different importer ( like https://wordpress.org/plugins/blogger-importer-extended/ but that will require the data to be hosted on a Blogger blog)

Comment: @PrayagVerma there is any other way by which i can import blogger post because client doesn't want to share is details.

Comment: @PrayagVerma now i am using blogger-importer-extended plugin but it also giving me an error i.e The importer has stopped unexpectedly! please tell me why i am getting this error.